# How can I create an equation that gives the maximum altitude of a water bottle rocket?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, rocket-science

I’m doing my extended essay on the physics of a water bottle rocket. Particularly the maximum flight altitude and what amount of water will give this result.

I’ve been working for weeks, going through available sources, trying to find an equation for the maximum height reached by a water bottle rocket but they’re all quite complicated and none of them actually give an “h = “ kind of equation. They’re all force balance equations.

I'm starting Year 12 now, taking Math and Physics HL in IB but what I've learned so far still isn't sufficient to understand these sources.

I know calculus 1 and can optimize.

Comment: You will probably have to do a numeric simulation on the water bottle rocket problem ... it's somewhat more difficult than it looks.

Comment: If you are going to write an essay then you need to understand the issues. Giving an equation of the form $h=....$ without understanding where it comes from is not going to impress your reader. You are better off writing the force balance equations if you understand them. If the sources are too difficult for you to follow don't use them.

Comment: I don't know why anybody would down-vote your question.  It is a perfectly legitimate physics question.  You stated your educational background.  This is a question you can carry with you for years, continually refining and expanding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem involves two parts. In part one, water is being pushed out and providing an upward thrust. In part two the rocket is in free-fall which is easy to calculate if you don't include friction.  In part one the thrust depends on the rate at which water is being ejected. This depends on the size of the nozzle and the pressure inside of the nozzle. This pressure depends on the depth of the water, the acceleration, and the pressure of the air left inside.  As the water goes out, the mass of the rocket, the pressure of the air inside (which is undergoing an adiabatic expansion) and the acceleration all change.    As Mr. White suggests, you will need a numeric simulation in which the value of each of the many variables is recalculated after each short interval of time (I would suggest starting with every 0.01 sec.).  In recent decades I have been doing simulations on an Excel spreadsheet on which formulas are easily propagated and entries are easily changed. Also results can be plotted on a graph.  If you can get a reasonable estimate for friction as a function of speed, you may want to also simulate part two.

Comment: And the real "gotcha" in all of this: I have seen actual thrust data from a high school device that was designed to measure the thrust from a water bottle rocket.  The data was very noisy, and strongly implied that there was a chaotic mixture of air and water exiting the rocket nozzle as water was expelled.  In the real world, two phase flow exists as the rocket accelerates.  Because there are several different flow regimes that can exist in two phase flow, this problem is probably impossible to accurately model.

Comment: I did forget to consider the thrust contributed by the remaining compresses air after the water has been expelled. (Measuring the thrust as a function of time would be a real challenge.)

Answer (score 0):

There's probably no way you are going to be able to come up with a general equation that takes in all the different parameters this situation could have, but you can probably come up with something for a very specific case.  That is, where you fix the geometry of the rocket and the surrounding air pressure / air characteristics (wind etc). You can then pick an initial combination of water volume and pressure, shoot off the rocket and record the height. Then you must replicate the experiment at least several times for that combo of water volume/pressure and then repeat the whole thing with a bunch of different combos of water/volume pressure (importantly realizing you cannot assume linearity).

Finally, plot out the data and hope there's a reasonable way to curve fit it.  The physics theory should help guide what sorts of equations would reasonably represent this problem, but there are going to be free parameters which have to be found through experimentation described above or very precise computer simulation.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've figured out all the forces exerted on the bottle rocket (probably the hardest part), all you need to do is use $F_{net}=ma$ and then apply kinematics equations. Remember that at the top of its trajectory, the rocket will have zero velocity. Solve for time $t$ to get to the top, then using this value, solve for height $h$ (the equation $\Delta x=\frac{(v_{i}+v_{f})t}{2}$ should be useful here--$x$ is a generalized coordinate for space, so it works for any direction, including upward!).